# How do I gracefully close my server?

Tags: c, sockets

I have a server that is listening to stdin (user) and other clients.

Let's say the server is connected to many clients (using `select` to control all file descriptors), and the user enters EXIT in the terminal.  This means the server should close itself.

What is the correct way to close the server gracefully?  Should the server go through all file descriptors and `close(fd)` all of them or just close the `listener` fd?  Alternatively, should I not close anything and just let the server process finish and exit?

I'm using only one thread in my program.

Thank you.

Comment: A simple `_exit()` will ensure the code to deal with unexpected disconnections is tested better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closing the listener `fd` means no more connections will be accepted. The nicest way to handle this would be to:

- Stop accepting connections
- Tell everyone to close (through your protocol)
- Wait for some time and then close the server

Closing a process automatically closes all its open file-descriptors. Telling everyone to close before you exit is just a convenience so as not to abruptly close the connection.

Answer (score 2):

For a "graceful disconnect" you should also call `shutdown(fd, SHUT_RDWR);` ( [shutdown()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/shutdown.html) ), so that you can assure that all data is sent and received before you close() the socket.

On a side note, if you're working under linux you might consider using [epoll](http://kovyrin.net/2006/04/13/epoll-asynchronous-network-programming/) instead of select.